# GNU/Linux: fast switching between keyboard layouts

Tags: linux, gnu

on x server environments i just open a terminal emulator (pressing + typing in `x-terminal-emulator` and pressing return on most graphical environments/window managers) and tping in

```
setxkbmap us
```

and i am just able to type in thinks like i am used to. After a reboot, or just relog in this case, the settings will be set again to the users default layout.

But how can i do the same thing while using a root shell on an linux console (tty1 for example)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the command [`loadkeys`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_loadkeys.htm). 
You can search the *keymaps* available with `locate keymaps`. 
After you can use E.g.:

```
loadkeys us
```

and

```
loadkeys -d          #  to restore the default or
loadkeys defkeymap   #  in case the sign `-` is hidden somewhere
```